# Is there any advantage in repeating the TITLE text in a META TITLE tag?

Tags: html, seo, meta-tags

Which is better?

### A:

```
<title>Mary had a little lamb</title>
```

### B:

```
<title>Mary had a little lamb</title>
<meta name="title" content="Mary had a little lamb">
```

**Is there any advantage (seo or otherwise) in putting all of the TITLE text into a META TITLE tag?**

Answer (score 1):

I don't think is the same, the  tag you should use always, as is used, between other things, by most search indexes; on the other hand the meta tag is not very clear how is used, some people say it helps to improve search results, others say it doesn't do anything...

[Here](http://www.webmarketingnow.com/tips/meta-title.html) is an article about it

Answer (score 0):

No. The meta title tag is not used by search engines as it is redundant with the `<title>` tag and because it can be abused like the meta keywords tag since its content is never visible on the web page. It also is not used by browsers to render the page.